# backup exec 2012: what are catalogs and inventories?

Tags: backupexec

in the backup exec 2012 environment what are the catalogs and the inventories ?
I have read the manual but honestly I have not understood.
I am sorry for my basic question but it seems that what I have written is not enough for serverfault..

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure you can simply look in the docs...but here's my definition...

**Catalog** = a list of the files/folders/dates/etc backed up WITHIN a backup file that BUE created.  Used to do a restore of files typically.  If the catalog has expired in the BUE database, then you'll need to run a catalog on the backup media in order to restore files from them.  It tells BUE what is inside the backup media.

**Inventory** = when run against a Library or Backup-to-Disk-Folder will inventory that location looking for backup files and listing them along with what media set they are in (and therefore when/if they are overwriteable, appendable, etc.).

So, let's say you have an LTO tape from 2 years ago.  You'd insert it, then run an Inventory on the tape library/drive.  This will tell BUE what is in the drive and what backup media files exist.  Then you'd run a catalog against those media files in order to see what actually exists WITHIN those backup media files to be able to restore.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was typing up an very similar response when yours came in... beat me to it :)

Comment: :) sorry mate.  I saw a BUE question and thought "I might actually know an answer today!"